# Return error list or result from java function

Tags: java, function, return

I know I cannot return multiple classes from a Java function, but I am trying to figure out which is the best/elegant way to return different kind of objects depending on the logic of the function.
My idea was to have functions return a list of Error (a class created to hold several error properties) or the function natural result if everything was ok.

I would like to apply the solution to many function inside the project, so the idea is to let them return a list of Error or whatever the function has to return.

I have also thought of some kind of Pair class, but that doesn't seem to exist by default in Java. That Pair class would be something like:

`Pair<List<Error>, T>`

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't you consider using a custom class for this scenario? It can have multiple error properties, which may or may not be null according to the scenario and there can be a happy result which can be obtained in case all the error properties are null. You could also provide a helper method for checking if the object actually has any error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Yash... I already have a class named Errors which holds a list or Error and my idea was to get some kind of global solution so any method could return either a class Errors or whatever the method has to return if everythong was Ok. I could create a class which holds an Errors property and the logical return value for each method, but that would mean a lot of auxiliar classes (almost 1 for each method!)

Comment: Hi Pep! I'm sure this will work out. But have you considered the fact that returning the list of errors from the methods in the first place is defying the definition of methods? I mean for a method named getPrimaryKeys() to return a list of errors instead of a list of Integers is defeating the purpose. I would rather that you return only the intended returnType from the methods and handle all other conditions using custom exceptions. That would be the most "JAVA" way of doing it.

Comment: Yes... I thought about that also (throwing exceptions instead of returning errors) but I wanted the method to be able to return more than 1 error (for example, validation of parameters... like "parameter 1 is not optional", "parameter 2 cannot be null" and "parameter 3 must be greater than 0"). Could I get that with exceptions?

Comment: Uhmm.. Can't we pass several parameters in the constructor of a custom Exception class? Or maybe a list of string information in the class and then a builder method to help the user work with it? I'm not sure if it works that way, but it is worth trying, right?